# displayName for each language is not used by LinkManager

Tags: multilingual, link-manager, versions

For an item I have 2 version for 2 languages with a different displayName for each. 
The displayName are :

- Item_01_EN for the EN version
- Item_01_FR for the FR version

Now the problem is, when I use `LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, opts)` with my opts.Language set to the FR culture, sitecore keeps generating an URL with Item_01_EN displayName instead of Item_01_FR.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you set in your options `useDisplayName = true` Have you tried it?

Comment: It won't, actually. But it's all covered in the linked resolution answer.

Comment: The problem was generating the link using the diplayname, or generating the link for a language different to the language used to get the item?

Comment: Item language, options language and context language in beautiful mix, yea ;-)   Not OPs fault.

Comment: The problem was generating the link using a displayName which varies depending on the language of the item :)

From what I understood, I'll have to load manually the item in the target language to pass it to my LinkManager.

I'll edit my first post with the solution, thank you guys !

Comment: Glad it worked out :-)  Please don't edit in solutions to the question text; it confuses search engines. And there is already a redirect in place to the solution answer. If you feel that the answer needs to be elaborated further, feel free to add an additional answer on the linked question :-)